# Weird bug with Entity Framework T4 Templates - Creating new code file

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, t4

I have an Entity Framework model with the Entity Objects T4 Template.  For some reason, now every time I change the model (say the model name is Model.edmx and the template Model.tt), it used to update the Model.cs file, but now it's creating Model1.cs and leaving Model.cs untouched.

Why is that?  Where does it define the file to update or gen to?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your .tt file contain a string like `fileManager.StartNewFile(entity.Name + ".cs");`?

Comment: I Ctrl + F the text "fileManager.StartNewFile" and nothing comes back...

Comment: Try to find and verify all the entries of `.cs` in .tt file's folder

Comment: I would unload project and open the csproj file in VS, look for Model1.cs.

Comment: @FuleSnabel Good call, it was referred to as Model1.cs.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sometimes happens when there's already a file named "Model.cs" in the output directory. Visual Studio then generates to another file named "Model1.cs". The way to fix that is by unloading the project file (right click the project) and edit it (right click again). Look for something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="Model1.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Model.tt</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="Model.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Model1.cs</LastGenOutput>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Replace "Model1.cs" with "Model.cs"

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="Model.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Model.tt</DependentUpon>
   </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <None Include="Model.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Model.cs</LastGenOutput>
   </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Reload project (right click)